# The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I tried to add a folder `iceberg/static/icon` into my repo but this fails with error:

```
shen-3:New Platform shen$ git add iceberg/static/icon
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
iceberg/static/icon
```

This is my .gitignore. I am really confused that I don't understand which item matches my file.

```
hello/
deploy_server/
gunicorn_start
Vida.env/

# IDE conf
.idea/
.vscode/

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
env/
build/
develop-eggs/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
.hypothesis/

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log
staticfiles/
local_settings.py
migrations/

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# pyenv
.python-version

# celery beat schedule file
celerybeat-schedule

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# dotenv
.env

# virtualenv
.venv
venv/
ENV/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
```

Is there any other reason this happens?

Any insight into why my folder isn't being added would be appreciated! :)
Thank you!

Full url you want `/Users/shen/Desktop/New Platform/iceberg/static/icon`

Comment: add a file in the folder called .gitkeep?

Comment: could you give the full paths?

Comment: updated........!

Comment: folders can not be added to git, there has to be at least one file inside

Comment: Do you have `iceberg/.gitignore`? `iceberg/static/.gitignore`? Are there any files in `iceberg/static/icon`?

Comment: Can you post the output for `git check-ignore -n -v iceberg/static/icon`

Comment: @1615903 `:: iceberg/static/icon`

Comment: There is one file named `company_logo.png` in this folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add the following line to your `.gitignore`:

```
!iceberg/static/icon
```

[The bang (!) character in a .gitignore file means to *not* ignore the specified path.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312826/4115031)

Comment: Actually this helps me out though looks so stupid :)

Answer (score 82):

To check what `gitignore` rule is causing a particular path to be ignored, run `git check-ignore`:

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/check
```

More info at [man git-check-ignore](https://gitirc.eu/git-check-ignore.html).

Comment: But it doesn't show anything. `git check-ignore -v iceberg/static/icon`

Comment: Use `--no-index` as well

Comment: Thanks @robrecord. Using `--no-index` worked. With `git check-ignore -v --no-index path/to/check`, found that the path was excluded in `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: Worked awesome. this point exactly where and which keyword causing problem in which gitignore file. Thanks.

Comment: This answer save me a lot of headaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I am unsure which line of your `.gitignore` triggers the ignoring.

But in such a case (when a file is ignored by default and you want to add it all the same), you can always do the following:

```
git add -v -f iceberg/static/icon
```

The `-f` flag is a shortcut for [--force](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--f)
(and the `-v` flag means [--verbose](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--v), which is often a useful mode when using `git add`)

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered the similar problem and this is how I solved it:

Most likely you have a global `.gitignore` file probably at `~/.gitignore`. And in your `~/.gitconfig` file there is a line like:

```
[core]
  excludesfile = /home/userName/.gitignore
```

Deleting the line from your config should solve the aforementioned issue.
To have Git ignore certain files across **all** repositories you can add the line back to your global `.gitconfig`.

Comment: This one worked for me, thanks  . It seems that SourceTree UI was adding the ignoring files into this path for some reason and not project specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use This will work for me :- `git add -f .`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer in addition to other answers, just in case it helps somebody -
In my case, it complained:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
lol/foo/include
lol/foo/baz/include
```

My .gitignore had:

```
include/
```

Removing that line from .gitignore solved my problem.

What that tells me is that even if your **offending path** has a **partial/sub path** to a **directory/sub-directory** somewhere in .gitignore, then that will also be ignored.

I checked your .gitignore file. It does NOT contain any of "iceberg" or "static" (although there is "staticfiles/" but that shouldn't matter) or "icon".

BTW, you might also want to search if there are other ".gitignore" files in *any* of your paths in the current .gitignore. But I'm not 100% sure if this is indeed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I managed to find an easy solutions.

There is a section in the manual `git -h` where they tell you about the option `-f`

> -f, --force "Allow adding otherwise ignored files"

However, I guessed and surprisingly it worked!

In the terminal type: `git add -f "the path"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to add a directory to the repo but on the other hand, it is somehow already inside `.gitignore` file. For example, in every project `node_modules` directory is in `gitignore` but if you

```
 cd node_modules
```

and inside this directory you run command:

```
 git add .
```

you will get this error:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
node_modules
```